# Laravel Eloquent сортировка

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Перед мной стоит задача выводить данные из базы в шаблон, при этом, посты у которых булево значение равно 0, должны идти вверху, а те у которых 1, внизу. Возможно ли в laravel сортировать данные из базы, по булевому полю?

Comment: Да, возможно, как и по любому другому полю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что мешает сортровать их как цифры? Булево значение в базе данных и представляет собой tinyint, и, соответственно, легко сортируется.

Но если важен точный порядок значений, можно использовать

```
$model->orderByRaw();
```

И там уже писать стандартную строку MYSQL

```
ORDER BY FIELD()
```